# what does it mean to take average of something that is continuous?

Tags: statistics, average

I had recently learned about "Centre of mass" in my physics class. I may be wrong but what I inferred from that lecture was "Centre of mass is more a mathematical concept where we assume a continuous body as a aggregate of infinitely many point masses, and then we assign co-ordinates to each of the points then, the Centre of mass's co-ordinate is the average of all the X and Y coordinates of all the points.

Say, I have three points in the 2d plane (0,0), (1,1), (2,2).

C.O.M = (1,1)

X co-ordinate of com = sum of all x co-ordinates / no. of co-ordinates

vice versa for Y co-ordinate.

Now, problem arises when I tried to find COM of a continuous system.

example :-

f(x) = x : x ranges from 0 to 1

I know the COM of this system should be (0.5,0.5) using my knowledge from the physics lecture, but when I tried to use the definition I had arrived i.e., "the Centre of mass's co-ordinate is the average of all the X and Y coordinates of all the points." I realized that I would have to take the average of the Infinite no. of points that lay on that line.

X co-ordinate of com = sum of all x co-ordinates / (no. of co-ordinates) <--- does this

become infinity ( I highly doubt it) or maybe it converges to something.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The centre of mass has a physical meaning and does not need a object to be made up of atoms to find it.  At a mathematical level it may require integration (in a sense the limit of summation).

Comment: the beauty of calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula:
$$\text{Mean}={1\over{b-a}}\int_a^b{f(x)dx}$$
Ex. $y=x^2$
$$M={1\over{b-a}}\int_a^b{x^2dx}=(a^2+ab+b^2)/3.$$

Comment: The result is $(a^2+ab+b^2)/3$ instead of $b^3/2-a^3/2$.

Comment: thx, I forgot the fraction before it